# Missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete' in django model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm getting this error: Missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete' in django model

```
from django.db import models

class Topic(models.Model):
   top_name = models.CharField(max_length=264, unique=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.top_name


class Webpage(models.Model):
   topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=264, unique=True)
   url = models.URLField(unique=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.name


class AccessRecord(models.Model):
   name = models.ForeignKey(Webpage)
   date = models.DateField()

   def __str__(self):
       return str(self.date)
```

I'm using `Django` v3.0 in `Pycharm`

[My code][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4RGE.png

Answer (score 1):

`on_delete` option on foreign keys is a required field. You have to use it in Django version 2.0 or higher.
The possible values for `on_delete` are found in [django.db.models docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete). For example you can change your models to these:

```
class Webpage(models.Model):  
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    .
    .
class AccessRecord(models.Model): 
    name = models.ForeignKey(Webpage, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

This will prevent deletion of the referenced object by raising `ProtectedError`

Answer (score 0):

Change these two models

```
class Webpage(models.Model):  
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    .
    .
class AccessRecord(models.Model): 
    name = models.ForeignKey(Webpage, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```